# Beacon API - Get the slot number from beacon node given the block number or hash

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm, beacon

`/eth/v1/beacon/headers/{block_id}` does not accept a block number as input.

What is the most efficient way to get the slot number given the block number / hash? What is `<hex encoded blockRoot with 0x prefix>`?